# Preview with QuickLook for .doc files won't work after latest Catalina update

Tags: macbook-pro, ms-office, catalina, quicklook

After the last Catalina update, when I try to preview `.doc` files with QuickLook it does not work, while `.docx` files are shown normally.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you restarted since? QuickLook has probably got itself into muddle.

Comment: Yes, I have restarted it, there is some improvement, but still not working consistently  (some doc are previewed some others not)

Comment: @unknowndomain ".doc"/".docx" aren't code!